# Is there a way to use hover effects with image mapping?

Tags: hover, mapping, imagemap, mousehover

For example, this is what I have as my image map right now, made using an image mapping site.

```
<div style="width:138px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<img id="Image-Maps_9201305251918089" src="http://www.image-maps.com/uploaded_files/9201305251918089_1_pizzaa.png" usemap="#Image-Maps_9201305251918089" border="0" width="138" height="71" alt="" />
<map id="_Image-Maps_9201305251918089" name="Image-Maps_9201305251918089">
<area shape="poly" coords="3,3,56,5,19,41,9,26," href="http://www.image-maps.com/home" alt="home" title="home"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="64,11,26,49,41,57,61,62," href="http://www.image-maps.com/links" alt="links" title="links"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="71,10,74,64,92,57,106,49," href="http://www.image-maps.com/about" alt="about" title="about"   />
<area shape="poly" coords="117,40,129,22,133,4,80,5," href="http://www.image-maps.com/botm" alt="botm" title="botm"   />
</map>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/suv8R/

However, this is what I want to achieve.

```
<style type="text/css">
#container {
position:fixed;
width:138px;
height:71px;
margin:10px;
background-color:yellow
}
#slice1 {
height:20px;
width:20px;
position:absolute;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left:0px;
}
#slice1 img:hover {
margin-top: 3px;
margin-left:-8px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#slice2 {
position:absolute;
margin-top: 4px;
margin-left:21px;
}
#slice2 img:hover {
margin-top: 8px;
margin-left:-3px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#slice3 {
position:absolute;
margin-top: 1px;
margin-left:69px;
}
#slice3 img:hover {
margin-top: 8px;
margin-left:3px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#slice4 {
position:absolute;
margin-top: 2px;
margin-left:72px;
}
#slice4 img:hover {
margin-top: 3px;
margin-left:8px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#slice1 img, #slice2 img, #slice3 img, #slice4 img {
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="slice1"><a href="/" title="home"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/8xsfla2/NWbmnda37/slice1.png"></a></div>
<div id="slice2"><a href="/" title="link2"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/8xsfla2/Nmjmnda5b/slice2.png"></a></div>
<div id="slice3"><a href="/" title="link3"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/8xsfla2/jAImnda5o/slice3.png"></a></div>
<div id="slice4"><a href="/" title="link4"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/8xsfla2/KR0mnda62/slice4.png"></a></div>
</div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YPsdj/1/

As you can see, each slice is a link, and I want each slice to slide out when I hover over it. The problem with the second example is that each slice is a transparent png, so the transparent parts of each png image overlap the other ones, so hovering on the entire slice doesn't work (especially the first and third slices).

So, if anybody has any solutions on how to make links like this work effectively, you help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!